# Missing Driver - Video Controller (VGA Compatible)

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, graphics-card

I have a HP 2000-2106TU Notebook PC running Windows XP.

I want to get the brightness keys to work. They are placed over the <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> buttons and are meant to be used in conjunction with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. But these combinations do not work, though other <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys such as the volume control keys do.

I see a missing driver for a device called `Video Controller (VGA Compatible)` in the Windows Device Manager. The hardware id is PCI VEN 8086 DEV 0106 SUBSYS_1858103C which a Google search suggests is in an Intel HD Graphics family, but I don't know where to locate the driver.

HP's driver scan does not help, as it does not show any missing driver related to video/graphics.

What can I do next?

Comment: This is all I can find for drivers. I looked through all the XP OS drivers and all they have is LAN drivers. but if you look under the other OS like Windows 7, it has graphics.

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=5269792&prodSeriesId=5259209&prodTypeId=321957&taskId=135&swLang=13

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. It says the 'Computer does not meet the minimum requirements'. maybe it expects Win 7 only. Although, it did mention DEV 0106 as one of the graphics cards supported.

Comment: tried autodetecting? http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/?iid=subhdr+dnlds_detect

Answer (score 1):

Intel's video cards only support in-service editions of Windows. Since Windows XP is no longer supported by Microsoft, Intel no longer provides drivers for it.

You may be able to find legacy drivers for Windows XP from your device manufacturer's website, however your drivers will no longer be supported, and problems (including security problems) will no longer be fixed.

Your best solution would be to upgrade to an in-service edition of Windows, such as Windows7.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems this more an issue of not having support for an outdated processor (Celeron). See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I am running Intel Celeron processor. The driver download for this chip is supposed to be [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop%20graphics%20drivers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Celeron%C2%AE%20Processors%20with%20Intel%C2%AE%20HD%20Graphics) but it is missing. I have contacted support for this.

There are Intel Graphics drivers of various other types for various other (newer) processors [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop%20graphics%20drivers&ProductProduct=2nd%20Generation%20Intel%C2%AE%20Core%E2%84%A2%20Processors%20with%20Intel%C2%AE%20HD%20Graphics%203000/2000)